# Strange java.util.Calendar behavior in API Level 23 and downwards

Tags: java, android, android-api-levels, java.util.calendar

When working with `java.util.Calendar` on Android, I stumbled upon an interesting bug: on API level 23 or lower some fields set by `Calendar.set(...)` won't be applied until `Calendar.get(...)` is called (as the get-method internally calls `complete()` ?)

This problem occurs, when setting the `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` multiple times, take a look at the following code:

`DateHelper.kt`

```
class DateHelper{
    companion object {
        fun getStartOfWeek(yearInformation : Date, weekNumber: Int, applyFix: Boolean = false): Date {
            val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
            cal.time = yearInformation
            cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, weekNumber)
            if(applyFix) cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, cal.firstDayOfWeek)
            return cal.time
        }
    }
}
```

`DateHelperTest.kt`

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class) 
class DateHelperTest{

    /** setting the week of month only once works */
    @Test
    fun shouldReturnCorrectStartOfWeek(){

        val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2018)
        val yearInformation = cal.time

        val weeknumber = 8 //Sunday = 18.02, Monday = 19.02

        val result = DateHelper.getStartOfWeek(yearInformation, weeknumber)
        cal.time = result
        val acualDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

        assertThat(acualDay, anyOf(equalTo(18), equalTo(19)))
    }

    /**
     * setting the week of month twice (calling DateHelper.getStartOfWeek multiple times)
     * doesn't work (for API level <= 23)
     */
    @Test
    fun shouldChangeStartOfWeekCorrectly(){
        val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2018)
        val yearInformation = cal.time

        var weeknumber = 8 //Sunday = 18.02, Monday = 19.02
        DateHelper.getStartOfWeek(yearInformation, weeknumber) //initial call

        weeknumber = 9 //incremented, Sunday = 25, Monday = 26 now
        val result = DateHelper.getStartOfWeek(yearInformation, weeknumber) //second, tested call
        cal.time = result
        val actualDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        assertThat(actualDay, anyOf(equalTo(25), equalTo(26)))
    }

    /**
     * same as shouldChangeStartOfWeekCorrectly() but with workaround
     * (internally calling cal.get())
     * */
    @Test
    fun shouldChangeStartOfWeekCorrectly_WithWorkaround(){
        val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2018)
        val yearInformation = cal.time

        var weeknumber = 8 //Sunday = 18.02, Monday = 19.02
        DateHelper.getStartOfWeek(yearInformation, weeknumber) //initial call

        weeknumber = 9 //incremented, Sunday = 25, Monday = 26 now

        /* date helper call changed */
        val result = DateHelper.getStartOfWeek(yearInformation, weeknumber, applyFix = true) //second, tested call
        /* date helper call changed */            

        cal.time = result
        val actualDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        assertThat(actualDay, anyOf(equalTo(25), equalTo(26)))
    }
}
```

[Example Project on GitHub with executable instrumentation tests](https://github.com/C0d3GGz/AndroidCalendarApiBug)

The provided workaround (`if(applyFix) cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)`) is rather unpleasant: how to fix this issue in a proper way?

Comment: Why not set year instead of cal.time = Date ?

Comment: @LanceToth because I use `new Date()` within my app to get the current year dynamically

Comment: Oh, well Calendar.getInstance() already contains the current year (obviously)

Comment: Devil’s advocate here. While I see that the behaviour is unexpected and not what you want, I don’t think it is in disagreement with the documentation.

Comment: The `Calendar` class is long outdated. The pleasant fix is to use [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) and [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead.